# Can complex queries be updated via DBGrids?

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access

I'm simultaneously teaching myself about Delphi's database architecture and [MS-Access] SQL. I understand how to hook together Tables and DBGrids, enjoying how changes in a grid are automagically edited, inserted, appended, updated, posted, etc. to the underlying table.

I also understand how I can open or execute an [ADO]Query and view the resulting data in a grid.

What I'm much foggier about changing Tables by editing a DBGrid displaying query results. In my online searches, it seems like all the examples I've found where query results are edited involve queries no more complex than 'SELECT ... FROM oneTable.' It seems like DBGrids are for working only with individual tables or displaying query results.

On my own, when I've tried working with query results involving two or more tables I always get an error of some sort (insufficient key column info, a missing parameter, or other messages). I feel like I'm missing something fundamental, or DBGrids are rarely used for editing anything other than individual tables. Do you have any suggestions where I might look to learn what I'm missing? The most commonly suggested links (like the db lessons at delphi.about.com) don't address the issue.

EDIT: Remou's response helps me a lot in explaining problems I've been having. So I'll edit my question slightly by generalizing beyond only MS-Access db's. Can complex queries be updated via DBGrids in other popular databases?

Comment: I cannot answer for Delphi, but in MS Access queries need to be correctly structured and include key columns if you want them to be updateable: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198446(office.10).aspx

Comment: @Remou Thank you for the response. I think the link you provided is going to prove invaluable to me.

Comment: The DBGrid part of the question is irrelevant. A 'select' query can not be used to update data when there is more than one table involved or if parameters are used.

Comment: @No'amNewman A select query can be used to update in MS Access if it is properly structured. Is this a limitation of Delphi? Because it is not usually a limitation of databases.

Comment: @Remou Please copy (or expand) your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot answer for Delphi, but in MS Access queries need to be correctly structured and include key columns if you want them to be updateable. This is usual for most databases and I suspect is more likely to be the cause of the problem than anything to do with Dephi itself.

More information:

- [When can I update data from a query?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa198446%28office.10%29.aspx)
- [Why is my query read-only?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with a `(ADO)DataSet > Provider > ClientDataSet` layout, then all you have to do is implement the [`Provider.OnGetTabelName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/Provider.TDataSetProvider.OnGetTableName) event.

Answer (score 0):

Usually i used this statement in update sql :
update  where  field = ;

yup, in my database design every table MUST HAVE a primary key so i can update EXACTLY ONE ROW.
this combination (table with primary key + update sql) for like a charm for me for years.
till now actually.

best regard
irawan